# Merge Visual Studio Solution into Gitlab

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio, gitlab

I have a local Web Application which's backend is written in C# with Visual Studio. Now I decided to use a source administration tool for it. My problem is, that I'm really confused how to migrate my solution into GitLab. In my opinion there is one solution and 6-8 projects in this solution. So I wanna try to create for each project a git repository. The only problem is, that if I'm cloning my projects they won't find the dependencies. What is the right way to check in everything, organize it right and get rid of dependencies problems?

In the moment I created a git subgroup "MYAPP" and added all angular frontend applications. I made one repo for every application. Now I want to add the c# projects which are containing the logic. These are devided in 5 projects and a core project which handles the entityframework.

I hope to get some good advices and best practices.

Sorry for my bad english and thanks to everyone who tries to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider carefully if you want to separate each project into a single repository. If your projects are only used as part of your solution and you never want to use them anywhere else as standalone modules or libraries, it's perfectly fine to put the whole solution and all projects in a single git repository.

If, on the other hand, you use or publish your projects as libraries, you can totally manage them as separate repositories. In this case, you would need a repository for your solution that includes your subrepositories as [submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) or [subtrees](https://blog.developer.atlassian.com/the-power-of-git-subtree/).

Managing subrepositories, however, always comes with a certain overhead. I would advise to avoid it if it isn't justified (i.e. if at this point in time your solution is the only one using your projects).

Comment: So in the moment it's fact, that the projects are never used anywhere else. One of my goals is to slowly replace the monolyth into microservices. Because of that I wanted to build a right repository right away. But your comment helped me alot thanks.

Comment: Keep in mind that your repository does not necessarily have to reflect your software architecture. It's pretty common to even have a bunch of completely different applications in the same repository (although this is arguably not the best approach, but still common). You can manage microservices in a single repo, no problem. But the moment other, unrelated, projects start to use your services, you should split that part of your repository (but no worries: it's all possible with git).